# Unexpected automatic login Laravel 7x

Tags: laravel, authentication, autologin, registering

My Laravel application automatically logs in after registering which I do not want. I use the `default app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` and inside that file I wrote my own `register()` method. There is no `$this->guard()->login($user);` inside this method. Automatic login only happens occasionally but every time it happens the application 'loaded' for a long time after registering.

Comment: If you use the default  `register()` method and don't overwrite it yourself, there is a  `$this->guard()->login($user);` call, as you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/auth-backend/RegistersUsers.php#L36)

Comment: @Remul Thank you. I edited my question. I actually do have my own register method in the file I specified. And this does not contain the function you mentioned. I also searched my project folder files but no where it calls that function. So I can't wrap my head around why it logs in sometimes.